# Routes how to hide them on the url bar rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My route file has the following in it for the root. what i want is when i click on say about it doesn't show me `http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/abou`t what i would like is either `http://127.0.0.1:3000/about`
or just the URL `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` like root dose. I'm running rails 3 if you can post a snip it of a route file that will do this or give me a url to see it at that would be great.

```
# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
# just remember to delete public/index.html.
root :to => "home#index"

# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, if you have a controller `home` with an action `about` and want to call about directly, you can do something in your routes like `match "/about" => "home#about" :as => :about`

if you want to call the route, for example by using a `link_to` you can say it like this:

```
<%= link_to "Home", about_url %>
```

you can do `rake:routes` to see all the generated routes, you'll see one mapped to `about` with `controller => home` and `action => about`

Then, when you call `http://localhost/about` it will actually call the home controller's about action

you can read more material about routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: i tried that it still displays it as http://127.0.0.1:3000/home/about No offense but that website is very hard to understand its decently not made for beginners like me or maybe i just need to see examples

Comment: never mind i got it i had my link_to set wrong lol got it working now

Comment: i had <%=link_to "Home", :controller=>"home", :action=>"about" %> and should have had <%=link_to "About", "/about" %> i hope that helps any one else that reads this looking for answers

Comment: well, what you did is not exactly ok. I'll edit my answer to explain better

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more details.

1. You should put the root route at the end of the file.
2. You need to delete the public/index.html file for the root route to take effect.
3. Make sure you have a home controller
4. Make sure you have a view called index in the views/home/ folder

Then `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` will display your index action

If you want your root to go to the about action, also change the route file to root :to => "home#about". Of course make sure you have an about view.

Comment: all that dose is redirects my route to the about page what i want is to hide the controller is there a way to do that i was hopping mabey :as => about or something would work but it didnt seem to work

Comment: do you have a better web page than the above maybe one that shows examples of what those commands do that page is very hard to understand for a beginner like me

Comment: thanks for the help i got it working i made a newbie mistake and had my link to set wrong